# Cannot find bean under name WeaponList

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts

```
 <html:select property="Weapon">
   <html:options collection="WeaponList" property="weaponIDPK" labelProperty="weaponName" />
 </html:select>
```

I'm creating a drop-down list to display different weapons in Struts  and I'm getting this error.

Can you tell me what are the missing pieces? Or possible errors?
Do I need to fix my Action file?

Im having problem on this part

```
collection="WeaponList"
```

Comment: Unrelated, but please see the bottom of [What are tags, and how should we use them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging); putting explicit tags in the title is redundant.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using Struts 2? There's no `<xxx:options>` tag in S2.

Comment: it's a combination, JSP and Strutsm, the syntax is JSTL

Comment: I'm asking if you're using *Struts 2*, which the question is tagged with. I ask because (1) the tag prefix in the JSP snippet (which includes no JSTL) is more commonly associated with Struts 1, and (2) there's no S2 "options" tag.

Comment: @DaveNewton i'll remove the struts2

Comment: How about the question content where you explicitly stated Struts 2?

Answer (score 2):

S2:

The missing piece is `WeaponList`, which should be named `weaponList`, and exposed in the action via a normal JavaBean-style getter, `getWeaponList`.

---

S1:

The collection needs to be available in the `ActionForm`.

---

Either:

Naming should follow standard JavaBean conventions, e.g., the first letter should be lower-cased, for a variety of reasons.